# 1970s or earlier comedic space opera film with garbage collecting space ship

Tags: story-identification, movie, tv

I saw this film in the late 1970s. I am unsure if it was made for TV or ever had a theatrical release (I don't *think* it was a TV show). Its production values were, say, somewhere between a B-movie of the era and Space 1999. I saw it on a B&W TV, so can't recall if it was produced in color or not.

The only bit I clearly remember was a scene where, what I believe was, the protagonists' spaceship went to collect some space garbage, and there was an external scene where the ship extends "arms" with grippers on the end and wrestles in comedic fashion with giant space trash.

**What was this film?**

Comment: @Valorum: I am all good with this being marked a duplicate, but I want to understand our policy better: the **answers** to the two questions are the same, but the **questions themselves** are quite different (i.e. land on different features from the series). Would there ever be a case where two questions share the same answer (e.g., "That's Asimov's Foundation series!"), but would not be marked as duplicates?

Comment: Story-ID questions get duped when it's **confirmed** that both questions are asking about the same property.

Comment: @Valorum Why bother marking as a dupe if it's already been answered?

Comment: @Valorum Thank you! That was the piece I was missing in my head: `[story-id]`. :)

Comment: @Clonkex Because another visitor to SFF.SE might search for something like "space garbage collection show" *or* "space pilot cloned from co-pilot's finger".

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is the short-lived TV series [Quark](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Series/Quark).

You can see them grappling on to the garbage bag in the clip below.

Comment: FWIW the full series (what there was) DVD is available on Netflix

Comment: Thanks for the edit!